# QGrapicsScene: Changing of QGraphicRects height only applied after second run

Tags: qt, pyside, qgraphicsitem

I am programming a stacked bar plot in `QGraphicsScene` using `QGraphicRectItems`. Everything works so far, but it seems as if I change the height of the `QGraphicsRectItems` straight after creating it with `setRect`, the height is not applied. Strangely, if I rerun the program the height is always changed to the same "random" values.

If I change the height of the `QGraphicsRect`s once more, using the same function everything works. Is there anything I need to do after creating a `QGraphicsRect` to "register" it or something?

Edit:

The same happens if I change the heights again. I need to do it twice to make the bars adjust their height correctly.

Code:

In my function I change the height of the (stacked) `QGraphicsRectItems` with:

```
accH = 0
for i, h in enumerate(data):
    geo = rects[i].rect()
    print "before\t\t\t", geo
    print "target height\t\t", h
    geo.setHeight(h)
    geo.setY(accH)
    rects[i].setRect(geo)
    print "changed geometry\t", geo
    print "geometry of updated rect", rects[i].rect()
    print "___"

    accH += h
print "-----"
```

`rects` is a list of previously created `QGraphicsItem`s.

Output of the print statements above with `data = [   98.   263.  6710.     0.]`:

First run:

```
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
target height           98.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 166.000000)
target height           263.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 263.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 263.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6351.000000)
target height           6710.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6710.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6710.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, -7068.000000)
target height           0.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
___
```

Second run:

```
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
target height           98.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 98.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 263.000000)
target height           263.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 263.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 98.000000, 1.000000, 263.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6710.000000)
target height           6710.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6710.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 361.000000, 1.000000, 6710.000000)
___
before                  PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
target height           0.0
changed geometry        PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
geometry of updated rect PySide.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 7071.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
___
```

What I just realized just now while making this output ready for stackoverflow, the problem seems that the height of each `QGraphicsRectItem` is the proper `height` - its `y value`. I tried now to first do `setY` and then `setHeight` on `geo` above. Then the prints suggest that the geometry (rect) of the  `QGraphicsRects` are correct. But on the `QGraphicsView` I do not see any change.

Comment: Could you edit your post by writing your code please ?

Comment: I added the part where I change the heights. The complete code is quite complex I can try to extract the essentials if necessary, but it might be a few lines of code..

Comment: tried calling QGraphicsScene::update after you change the height?

Comment: yes, and it does not help. The `QGraphicRects` are created properly. If I do not change their size, they are displayed correctly. But if I touch their size, the height is set to strange values.

Comment: I added some debug output. The problem seems to be that I change `y` and `height` of the `QRect` at the same time, as `y` is subtracted from the overall `height`

Comment: I think I solved it. The problem was that I did first call `setHeight()` and then `setY` on the `QRect` of the `QGraphicsItem`. If I do it otherwise around stuff starts to work.

Comment: Please post an answer to your question if you've found a solution. Answers don't belong in the question. (Solved or other tags either.)

Comment: Show a fixed part of the scene with `setSceneRect` and see if then things change.

Comment: Sorry I solved my problem already. I had updated the question-title to Solved and edited the solution in the question, but it was removed by Mat. I posted the solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem eventually.

What one has to do is to call `setY` before `setHeight` on the `QRect` defining the geometry of the `QGraphicsRect`.